# How to get Rails 3 to run in production mode on server w/ Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, capistrano, passenger

Hi I'm running Passenger/mongo/Rails 3.2 (no activerecord or mysql) with a Capistrano deploy script.

I'm trying to get my app to run in production mode on my linux server.

In my apache config file i have the following...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName example.com
 ServerAlias www.example.com
 DocumentRoot /srv/www/example.com/current/public
 ErrorLog /srv/www/example.com/current/log/error.log
 CustomLog /srv/www/example.com/current/log/access.log combined
 PassengerDefaultUser www-data
  <Directory /srv/www/test.example.com/current/public>
     AllowOverride all
     Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
 RailsEnv production
</VirtualHost>
```

EDIT: In my environment.rb file I no longer have the following...

```
RAILS_ENV="production"
RAILS_ENV.freeze
```

In my Capistrano deploy.rb I have the following...

```
set :rails_env, "production"
```

**EDIT:** But when I deploy via capistrano or do a sudo service apache2 restart.  It says apache restarts but the server never comes up when i access the url.

Comment: are you sure your server setting is right? like is example.com maps to your server? and did you add example.com to your hosts?

Comment: Yes Jun1st, the settings work if I simply use those settings but have the apache config file set to RailsEnv Development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like an unusual problem. I have deployed many applications with similar or identical stacks without incident.

Try this:

1. Please remove any custom code (related to this issue) from your environment.rb file.
2. Remove the rails_env variable from your deploy file
3. Make sure to leave "RailsEnv production" inside your Apache virtual host config
4. SSH into the server and restart Apache manually

I will check in the morning, but I believe that restart task for mod_rails is no good, I think I have hooked in a manual Apache restart after the deploy. Not sure why, think it has something to do with the fact that "current_path" is only a symlink or perhaps "PassengerMinInstances" is preventing a new passenger thread from spawning with the modified code. All speculation.

Comment: ok this is on the right track.  I discovered doing a cap deploy doesn't re-pick up the apache config file changes, so a manual restart is necessary.  The issue now is when I do a manual restart and have RailsEnv production in the file, it says it restarts but the server never displays the page again (get an error message like this page - http://www.jkldfajjdflfadlfadllda.com/).  Must be a start up issue in production mode, but i check the mongo and apache logs and i don't see any error. Do I need to have something regarding precompiling assets in my cap deploy file?

Comment: @HelloWorld yea, cap has in build tasks for asset precompilation, just add __ load 'deploy/assets' __ in your capfile and you're done :)

Comment: @HelloWorld also, check the rails log! The passenger spin up issue may  not be logged to apache or mongo logs. The log/production.log should contain details of spawn failure. I usually find this easier than visiting passenger logs... which is also an option ;)

Comment: +1 assets precompile line works, thanks. Its still failing after restart though, i went into app_base/current/logs and vi production.log but didn't see any errors.  Not sure if that was the log file you were mentioning.  Trying at the moment to test production mode locally to see if my config/environments file is good or not.

Comment: when I deploy via capistrano or do a sudo service apache2 restart. It says apache restarts but the server never comes up when i access the url (if I have it set to production in the apache config), it starts up fine in dev mode.

Comment: while i haven't fully resolved this issue yet, this answer provided two helpful points, thus the +50 bounty

Comment: @HelloWorld thanks mate! So where have you reached now? By the way - the problem now looks like passenger's apache2 module didn't build correctly or isn't specified like it should be in the apache2 conf file. When you say "dev mode" i presume all you're doing is removing the `RailsEnv production` from the vhost block, or something else?

Comment: was able to resolve this, there were issues with my production.rb file, thanks again for the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 3.x apps that come with a `config.ru` file you should be using the `RackEnv` parameter in your `VirtualHost` configuration:

```
RackEnv production
```

You really should not be force-setting `RAILS_ENV` inside of `environment.rb`. That's bound to cause all kinds of problems.

Comment: removed environment.rb stuff, placed RackEnv production in apache config, ran cap deploy, home page still outputs "Running in development mode" after refresh.

Comment: What does `rails console` fire up in?

Comment: When I go into the app directory on my server and run 'rails c' it fires up in development mode.

Comment: I usually set `export RAILS_ENV=production` for `bash` in either `.bashrc` or `/etc/profile.d/rails.sh` where that kind of thing is supported. Note that this environment setting doesn't apply to Apache, that's what the `RackEnv` setting is for.

Comment: I think the POSIX environment variable RAILS_ENV is being used, but the ruby constant RAILS_ENV is obsolete.

Comment: Under earlier versions of Rails 3 it was flagged as deprecated but the `RAILS_ENV` constant appears to have been removed entirely from Rails 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

On my production environment (application name conflux), I have RailsEnv production inside the  tag.

```
<Directory /var/www/conflux/current/public>
  RailsEnv production
  PassengerAppRoot /var/www/conflux/current
  Allow from all

  #Turn off MultiViews, which is incompatable with Passenger.
  Options -MultiViews
</Directory>
```

I agree not to set RAILS_ENV inside environment.rb.  For one thing, RAILS_ENV is a constant, and I think if it is used (and before Rails 3) it is set before entering the environments.  So, it may already be set, and as a constant, will not change.

I also am not sure that RAILS_ENV is used in Rails 3 any more.

Comment: tried this but also no dice.  Perhaps restarting the app through capistrano is skipping the changes to apache config?

Comment: `RAILS_ENV` is still around, but `Rails.env` is the preferred way of doing it in Rails 3.x.

Comment: I went directly into the console, and typed RAILS_ENV.  I get NameError: uninitialized constant RAILS_ENV.  I don't think RAILS_ENV is getting set or is read in Rails 3, at least not in Rails 3.1 for me.

Comment: This is the way to do it.  Be sure to restart apache after making the change.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pre-compiling the assets, Once precompiled, the assets are placed in public folder and then only you will be able to run it successfully in production mode. try this `rake assets:precompile` if it is jruby then `jruby -S rake assets:precompile`.

If the server is in production mode, asset pipeline and asset server needs to be set to "TRUE" in production.rb

Comment: rake assets precompile is already executed through the capistrano deployment script. I have config.assets.compile = false in my production.rb file but I don't believe this shouldn't prevent apache from starting.

Comment: you should give it a try i.e change that parameters to 'true'. If that does not work, best way to do is look at the development.log file to see what actually is the issue! Also please post the details of logs if you are in doubt!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this is the permissions settings for your directory

```
<Directory /srv/www/**test.example.com/**current/public>
     AllowOverride all
     Options -MultiViews
</Directory>
```

In which case, wouldn't this have to be the same as your document root setting

```
DocumentRoot /srv/www/**example.com**/current/public
```

Not that familiar with Capistrano or apache, but i've always thought these would need to be the same.